# Gtk Perl: Removing an item from a Gtk2::ComboBox by its name, rather than index

Tags: perl, combobox, gtk

While working with Perl and Gtk2, I have to programmatically remove an option from a drop-down (ComboBox). While I'm aware that `$combo_box->remove_text ($position)` will do the trick in one shot, I need to remove the option based on its *name* (entered by the user).

I'm unable to find a method that can return the index of an item by its name. Could someone help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit unclear what you mean by "name"; combo box items don't have names. If the combo box is textual, then each item is made up of text, but that text isn't a name. You could have the same string in all items for instance, which would make it very unclear which one you want to delete.

I think you're going to have to implement it youself, by iterating over the combo box's underlying tree model. Then it's up to you if you want to just delete the first match, continue searching to find all of them.

Comment: I meant "string value" by name. But I understand the point you raise - the string value of more than one item could be the same. Thank you.